# Using CONCAT with CASE statement not working correctly

Tags: mysql

i have a following table in MySQL called 'books'

[image]

#### What I want

I want to select `author_lname` and the number of books each author has written **BUT** i if the number of books written by any author is `1` then it should be displayed as `1 Book` and if number of books written is greater than `1` then i want to concatenate the word `Books` with the number of books written.

#### This is what I tried

So to achieve this, i tried following query

```
SELECT author_lname,
       CASE
          WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN '1 Book'
          ELSE CONCAT(COUNT(*),' Books')
       END AS 'Book Count'
FROM books
       GROUP BY author_lname, author_fname;
```

#### Result of the above query

[image]

#### Question

As you can see, the output of the query is not what i want. Please tell me why am i getting this output, what am i doing wrong and how can i get the desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a cast around the CONCAT ;)

```
SELECT author_lname,
   CASE
      WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN '1 Book'
      ELSE CAST(CONCAT(COUNT(*),' Books') AS CHAR)
   END AS 'Book Count'
FROM books
   GROUP BY author_lname, author_fname;
```

Comment: I am taking an online course on `MySQL` and the instructor did exact same thing as i did to get the desired output and it worked for him. Could that be an issue related to different version of `MySQL` ? And also could you please explain the reason why we need a `cast` around `CONCAT` ?

Comment: Well, I remember that MySQL Query Browser which we used in my previous company also displayed text that was a BLOB. I am not exactly sure why your version results in a BLOB - might be something with your MySQL version or configuration...